# count = 1, but -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array

Tags: objective-c, core-data

Here is my fetch request:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Test" inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"theId == %@", testId]];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
NSArray *theFetchArray = [[self managedObjectContext] executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];
Test *test;
if (theFetchArray.count > 0) {
    test = [theFetchArray objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"%@", test.value); //ERROR THROWN HERE
}
```

"count" is 1 and if I `NSLog(@"%@", test)`, it returns the instance of Test correctly - with "value" present. I set a breakpoint, and both the object within theFetchArray and the test object look like they're correct and contain "value".

Why is this happening?

P.S. - I found this [Other StackOverflow post similar to my scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18172177/nsarray-count-1-but-im-getting-index-0-beyond-bounds-for-empty-array-error)

This is the EXACT problem I'm experiencing. But no answers, unfortunately.

Comment: What is the type of `test.value`? Is it a string, or is it an integer or some other primitive type?

Comment: can you share crash log?

Comment: It really only said "-[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array". I can get more information if you need!

Comment: Can give more detail about your Test class ?

Comment: It contains Id (NSNumber) and value (NSNumber). It's an entity in core data

Comment: And test.value and test.id have already been set in the above example.

Comment: Is this code executed on the same thread where the context is created and supposed to be used?

Comment: Interesting point, @AlexeiKuznetsov, but I'm running it from the AppDelegate - main thread.

Comment: Just found that if I use NSManagedObject instead of the class - and then just do [managedObject valueForKey:@"value"] - it worked. Why is this working but not the class getter/setters?

Comment: @objectiveccoder001: Try to rename the attribute. This is just a guess, but some attribute names just "don't work", such as "deleted" or "updated". Perhaps "value" is also special.